# How to generate image jpg from html + css in android programatically?

Tags: android, html, image-processing

`Using android M`, This android java native app is POS app that have functional to print receipt to termal printer by image over Bluetooth. *So* I need to **generate image** as JPG file by using form that ready designed by **html** file. In this template contain CSS and javascript in local storage of android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying the receipt html in, say, a WebView, you can basically take a screenshot of the WebView and save it as a bitmap, then write it out to external storage (you'll need to add permissions for writing to External Storage).  Once saved as a bitmap, you'll have to figure out how to print it to the terminal printer.

There is another Question that shows the code for how to do this here:

[How to programmatically take a screenshot on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)